# Error message: index out of bounds, in a nested loop?

Tags: python

I am using a nested loop to define a matrix, but I keep receiving an error :

`IndexError: index 127 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 127`.

I receive this error in the last line, by `coeffs[i,i+1]`. This error is not returned during the earlier nested loop where I also have `coeffs[i,i+1]`. 
I have tried substituting just floats on the right hand side of `coeffs[i,i+1]`, and the error remains, so it is definitely here the issue lies. I have also tried `range(0,n+1)`, and this does not change anything.
As I understand it, Python sees the i+1 index and immediately decides that it could find an element that doesn't exist. However, my matrix is nxn in size and I have already given it the boundary conditions `for i == n`. I have tried the substitution `elif i != 0 and i != 1`, but it does not help. (Funcs is a vector I am also defining which is not producing any problems.) Any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance.

```
for i in range(0,n):

    if i == 0:
        coeffs[i,i] = 1
        coeffs[i,i+1] = 0
        funcs[i] = Tb
    if i == n:
        coeffs[i,i] = 1
        funcs[i] = Th
    else:
        coeffs[i,i] = -2
        coeffs[i,i-1] = 1+(w[i]*delz/2*kappa)
        coeffs[i,i+1] = 1-(w[i]*delz/2*kappa)
```

As below

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-f2fa3a661305> in <module>()
 39         coeffs[i,i] = -2
 40         coeffs[i,i-1] = 1+(w[i]*delz/2*kappa)
---> 41         coeffs[i,i+1] = 1-(w[i]*delz/2*kappa)
 42 
 43
```

IndexError: index 127 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 127

Comment: please share the stacktrace of the error (edit the question and add the stack trace as an extra code block below)

Comment: if you loop through a list of 5 things, and then when your on the fifth thing you try and grab index+1, what will happen?

Comment: Maybe it's just the identation

Comment: @Quinn I understand this, Python is looking for something that isn't there, but I'm trying to define the inside of the matrix. Do you have any suggestions on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The last item in range(0,n) is n-1, not n

Comment: Can you explain further? I have tried altering it to range(0,n+1), but as I said this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Change the -“ if i==n” to “if i==n-2”

Comment: This did not work. I changed it to n-1, and the error stopped coming up, but this gives the incorrect matrix. This produces a matrix whose first element is -2, and as per the first nested loop, I'd like it to be 1.

Comment: What do you mean by first element? coeffs[i,i] ? If so - please provide the right code... In the code above it must be equal to 1.  You can also just go line-by-line and debug your code....